# Winforms and VSTO Excel ShowDialog() partly modal

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, excel-addins, winforms-interop

The strangest thing ever!

I'm working on an Excel add-in, the ribbon has some buttons that pop some modal dialogs. all of those dialogs are initiated in the same way from the button click event in the ribbon:

```
SampleForm sample = new SampleForm();
sample.ShowDialog();
```

so far everything works great - when the modal form appears I can't change cells selection and click the ribbon until the form is closed.

**except for one form.**
when showing this form only the upper part of excel isn't active (i.e. not responding to mouse clicks) but I still can select cells in the worksheet. plus, I can't hear the beep sounds when the modal open and I click on the ribbon items - as I hear when the other modal windows open.

when this bad form is open I can see that `this.modal = true` plus since the ribbon clicks are disabled (without making a sound) it's actually partly modal.

**My questions are:** 
does it sound familiar? where to look for an answer? what can be the cause for that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What made the modal window to become partly modal is changing the cursor state of excel.

```
excelApp.Cursor = XlMousePointer.xlWait;
```

Removing this call fixed the issue